# Variable has different values inside and outside a function

Tags: javascript, function, models

I'm trying to set the value of an ID in the variable newID.
To "fill" the variable I'm reading a model like this:

```
press: function() {
    var newID = 0;
    oModel.read("/Delivery", null, null, true, function(oData) { 
        newID = oData.results[oData.results.length - 1].ID;                   
        console.log(newID);

    }
    console.log(newID);
}
```

The first console.log gives me the value that I want, but the second one gives me 0 (the first condition set). I've tried using the incremental operator += and using this.newID but all in vain.

It really is a silly problem, probably something the way I'm calling newID on the console or the way I increment it inside the function...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `read` is async

Comment: @Maxzeroedge: the newID variable its declared in the press function constructor, so it is accessible in the read scope (closure) and after that in the same scope using the second console.log().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was going to be a comment but it is so huge, so take it as a comment:

It is possible that the oModel.read function is asynchronous so when you execute the code basically that happen is this:

1) You declare the variable as 0.

2) You execute read function.

3) You execute console.log(var) => this print 0. (Because read does not finished yet and it is still 0 at this point).

4) Read function finished it work assign the desired value to var and execute console.log(var) => this print the desired value.

If that is the case you can implement something like this:

```
var press = function() {
    var newId = 0;
    function callback() {
       console.log(newId); 
    }
    oModel.read("/Delivery", null, null, true, function(oData) {
        newID = oData.results[oData.results.length - 1].ID;                   
        console.log(newID);
        callback();
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly!! It turns out that .read was really async, this structure solved the problem :)
Thanks, really appreciated your help!